# Chrome Developer Tools - Can't Edit Styles Properties

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm experiencing an unusual issue in Chrome Developer Tools and am unsure if I pressed a shortcut or something.

My issue is that whenever I try and edit a CSS property I can only press a single key after clicking into the property and it immediately exits from the property.

For example, the styles pane might include something like below:

```
#test-id {
  height: 100px;
}
```

Usually, you can click on the '100px' entry and use your up arrow to increase the value. Or type a new value, ect.

However, if I click into the property and press any key it submits that single key and my cursor exits the property.

Did I press something like num lock (tried it..) that is causing this?

Answer (score 3):

There's not much info here, so I'll list out things to try, and then you can reply in the comments whether or not that helped. I'll update my answer after each comment.

First things first, open up an incognito window (`cmd`+`shift`+`n` on mac, `ctrl`+`shift`+`n` on windows / linux) and try to reproduce the behavior. If this solves the problem, then some setting or extension in your Chrome profile is messing with DevTools.